# What shortcode will see the WooCommerce product I'm viewing and return the value/products inside the bundle-sells field?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I need to create a short code that access the WooCommerce product I'm currently viewing and fetches the products inside the Bundle-sells field so that I may insert the short code into a custom theme I am building. I started a short code, but it is not working, where am I going wrong?

Now each product has a product data table and one of the menu tabs is "linked products". Inside exists the bundle-sells field which at the moment is filled with 3 other related products I want to display along with the original product once it's being view. Because I'm using a custom template this option doesn't work just by filling out the fields therefore, I have to manually bring them in by creating a short code and inserting this short code into my template.

These are the 2 short codes I've come up with and don't work.

1st shortcode:

```php
function fetch_bundle_sells_products() {
    // Get the global product object
    global $product;  
    // Get the current product ID
    $product_id = $product->get_id();
    $product_object = wc_get_product( $product_id );
 
    // Get the bundle-sells data
    $bundled_items = new WC_Bundled_Item_Data( $product_object );
 
    // Check if there are any bundled items
    if ( ! $bundled_items->get_items() ) {
        return 'No bundled products found.';
    }
 
    // Fetch each product in the bundle-sells array and generate HTML
    $bundled_products_html = '<ul>';
    foreach ( $bundled_items->get_items() as $bundled_item ) {
        $bundled_product = $bundled_item->get_product();
        if ( $bundled_product ) {
            // Generate an HTML list item with the product's name
            $bundled_products_html .= '<li>' . esc_html( $bundled_product->get_name() ) . '</li>';
        }
    }
    $bundled_products_html .= '</ul>';
 
    // Return the HTML list of bundled product names
    return $bundled_products_html;
}
 
// Register the shortcode with WordPress
add_shortcode( 'bundle_sells', 'fetch_bundle_sells_products' );
```

2nd shortcode:

```php
function fetch_bundle_sells() {
    // Get the global product object
    global $product;
    // Get the current product ID
    $product_id = $product->get_id();
    $type = $product->get_type();
    $output = '';
    if($type == 'bundle'){
        $name = $product->get_name();
        $regular_price = $product->get_price();
        $price = $product->get_regular_price();
        $sale_price = $product->get_sale_price();
        $output .= '<ul class="bundle-detail">';
        $output .= '<li class="bundle-sale-price"><b>Bundle Price : </b>'.$sale_price.'</li>';
        $output .= '<li><b>Bundle Title : </b>'.$name.'</li>';

        // Get the bundle_sells_form field
        $bundle_sells_form_ids = get_post_meta($product_id, 'bundle_sells_form', true);
        $bundle_sells_form_ids = explode(',', $bundle_sells_form_ids); // If the ids are stored as a comma-separated string

        foreach($bundle_sells_form_ids as $id){
            $output .= '<li><b>Bundle Item : </b>'.get_the_title($id).'</li>';
        }

        $output .= '<li class="bundle-reg-price"><b>Regular Price : </b>'.$price.'</li>';
        $output .= '</ul>';
    }

    // Return the HTML list of bundled product data
    return $output;
}
// Register the shortcode with WordPress
add_shortcode( 'bundle_sells_shortcode', 'fetch_bundle_sells' );
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated!